# Initialize a double pointer with 123.0 in c++

Tags: c++

I have tried the c++ code

```
double* p;
*p = 123.0;
```

in vs 2010, and it broke off because the pointer hasn't been initialized. But I remember I have read in a blog(forget which one...), that the 123.0 is a const value，so p is pointing to a const value now, you can use *p to get 123.0 but you cannot change the value. Which one is the truth?? Thank you!

Comment: Yes, the literal `123.0` is a constant, but it still doesn't change the fact that `p` itself isn't actually pointing anywhere to begin with. The dereference operator `*` takes what the pointer *is pointing to*, and if the pointer is not pointing anywhere you have [*undefined behavior*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

Comment: Your code exhibits undefined behavior.

Comment: @Ke Reread the chapter on pointers.

Comment: Pointer points to no valid address, so you can't store a value through it.

Comment: Maybe you are confusing with the valid `const char* const p = "123.0";`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your approach is wrong since `double* p;` only declares a pointer, but it is uninitialized so when you do `*p = 123.0;` it triggers an undefined behaviour.

You need to point p to a valid double location so you can modify it.

Neil's answer is partially correct. In his example, you cannot change `*p` anymore like you do in your question. You need to get rid of the const. In that answer, `p` points to memory on the stack.

If you want to create a heap-allocated double, you would use the `new` keyword.

```
double* d = new double;
*d = 123.0;
```

However, you have to make sure to `delete` this memory after you are done using it.

```
delete d;
```

Since you are using MSVC 2010, which includes some C++11 features, the better way to do the same would be to use `unique_ptr`. It acts the same as a raw pointer, but it will manage the memory allocated by the pointer ... i.e. it will automatically call delete once it goes out of scope.

```
unique_ptr<double> d = unique_ptr<double>(new double);
*d = 123.0;
// when d goes out of scope, the memory will be deleted as well
```

Answer (score 6):

`p` doesn't point anywhere and you tell it to store value `123.0`. Where should it go? This is undefined behaviour.

If you want it to point to a constant value in a memory address that will stick around, try

```
static const double d = 123.0;
const double* p = &d;
```

I can't suggest anything more without context of what you are trying to do.